# Skip value of (sub)array if match exists

Tags: php, arrays

I have both an array (teams) and a subarray (team members). I would like to echo a list of all matches but I would like to check for a team member and if exists not to echo.

Is in_array() the right function?

```
array
 -- Team 1
    --- Anne
    --- Julia
    --- Jack
 -- Team 2
    --- Tom
    --- Lisa
    --- James
 -- Team 3
    --- James
    --- Julia
    --- Donald
```

Checking for Jack should "echo"

```
array
 -- Team 2
    --- Tom
    --- Lisa
    --- James
 -- Team 3
    --- James
    --- Julia
    --- Donald
```

Checking for James should "echo"

```
array
 -- Team 1
    --- Anne
    --- Julia
    --- Jack
```

My current code echoes following if James exists.

```
array
 -- Team 1
    --- Anne
    --- Julia
    --- Jack
 -- Team 2
    --- Tom
    --- Lisa   
 -- Team 3
    --- Julia
    --- Donald
```

But in case a match of team members is found, i want to 'skip' the entire team and not only a single member.

Comment: `My current code` what does your current code look like?

Comment: Can you show how you're checking?

Comment: $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed

foreach($characters[data] as $teams) {

for ($members = 0; $members <= count($teams[abc])-1; $members++) {

   if($teams[teamnames][$members][name] == "James" OR $flights[route][$stops][operating_carrier] == "Julia")
{
echo "skip this team - not only this entry";
}

///  some more echoes of values from array
}
echo "<br />";
  }

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `foreach`

```
$arr = [
  'Team 1' => [
        'Anne','Julia','Jack'
    ],
  'Team 2' => [
        'Tom','Lisa','James'
    ],
  'Team 3' => [
        'James','Julia','Donald'
    ]
];
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  if(!in_array('James',$val)){
     $res[$key] = $val; 
  }
}
```

search `James` : [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/2ONCi)

search `Jack` : [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/7sYUf)

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. To make it easier for me and to understand better, i thought it might help to work With "teams, team names and team members". As I am a beginner, i kindly appreciate if you would help me again, as it is actually about following:

[data]
[data][route] 
[data][route][0] // flight 1 in a route
[data][route][1] // flight 2 in a route
[data][route][2][airline] // name of airline of flight 3

So basically what i want to achieve is not to echo [data][route] if the [data][route][$i][airline] value = XY 

Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `foreach` loop, you can loop through the `multi-dimensional array` of teams, and then use `in_array` on each sub `array` to check if the name exists within the team. Using `<pre>` and `print_r` you can pretty print out the array of the teams that don't contain the name you're searching for.

** My answer uses the same logic as @Rakesh's (his is nice, simple and effective), but I may have over-explained my logic more with my naming conventions, etc.

```
<?php

function checkForTeamMember($memberName, $teams) {
    echo "Looking for teams without: ".$memberName ."<pre>";       
    $teamsToPrint = [];
    foreach($teams as $teamKey => $memberArray) {
        if(!in_array($memberName, $memberArray)) {
             $teamsToPrint[$teamKey] = $memberArray;
        }
    }
    print_r($teamsToPrint);
    echo "</pre>";
}

$teamGroups = [];
$teamGroups['Team 1'] = array('Anne', 'Julia', 'Jack');
$teamGroups['Team 2'] = array('Tom', 'Lisa', 'James');
$teamGroups['Team 3'] = array('James', 'Julia', 'Donald');

checkForTeamMember('James', $teamGroups);
checkForTeamMember('Jack', $teamGroups);
?>
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/DsQc2